# Sesión en PHP se cierra al hacer algún movimiento dentro de la página

Tags: php

Mi problema radica en que inicio sesión, hago un movimiento dentro, por ejemplo, publico un artículo, pero cuando quiero editarlo, me saca a la página principal.

No sé qué sea el error, tengo nociones de que es la sesión, pero la verdad no estoy seguro. He estado investigando acerca de las sesiones con PHP, pero la verdad no sé que hacer.

Este es mi modal para iniciar sesión:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelleby="modal-3" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title text-success" id="exampleModalLabel"><i class="fas fa-users-cog"></i> INGRESAR</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close text-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
            </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form action="./clases/login.php" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label text-muted"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Usuario</label>
              <input type="text" name="user" class="form-control" placeholder="Tú Usuario Aquí..." required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label text-muted"><i class="fas fa-user-lock"></i> Contraseña</label>
              <input type="password" name="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Tú Contraseña Aquí..." required>
            </div>
            <div class=" modal-footer">
              <button type="submit" name="btnIngresar" class="btn btn-outline-success"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Ingresar</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div
```

Mi código PHP:

```
<?php
    include '../conexion/conexion.php';
    error_reporting(0);
    $usuario = $_POST['user'];
    $contrasena = $_POST['pass'];
    $iniciar= $_POST['btnIngresar'];

   if (empty($usuario) || empty($contrasena)) {
    }else{ 
    if (isset($iniciar)) {
        $sql = "SELECT usuario, clave FROM admin WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND clave='$contrasena' ";
        $execute=$conexion->query($sql);
        $filas = $execute->fetch_row();
        if ($filas[0] == $usuario && $filas[1] == $contrasena) {
            $_SESSION['usuario']= $usuario;
            header("Location: ../blogI/blog.php");
        }else{
            echo "<script>
            alert ('Usuario o Clave Incorrectos');
            window.location = '../index.php';       
        </script>";
        }
    }
    }
?>
```

Ahora la página donde me dirige cuando inicio sesión:

```
<?php include ("../conexion/conexion.php");?>
<?php   include ("includes/header.php");?>

<div class="container">
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['message'])){?>
    <div class="alert alert-<?= $_SESSION['message_typed'] ?> alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <?= $_SESSION['message'] ?>
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    </div>
<?php session_unset(); }?>
<form action="save.php" method="POST"  enctype='multipart/form-data' name="formblog">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="colFormLabelLg" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Titulo Del Articulo</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="titulo del articulo" name="title" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Autor</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Autor" name="autor"value="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="colFormLabelLg" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Imagen</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="img">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="colFormLabelLg" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Articulo</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="txtArticle" placeholder="Introduzca su texto Aquí..." name="articulo"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
    <input class='btn btn-outline-primary' name='btnGuardar' type='submit' value="Publicar Articulo">
</form>

<script>
  (function(){
    var formulario = document.getElementsByName('formblog')[0],
      elementos = formulario.elemnts,
      boton = document.getElementById('btnGuardar');

      var validarTextArea = function(e){
        if (formulario.articulo.value.length <=200) {
          alert ("El Articulo debe tener mas de 200 caracteres o llena todos los campos :(");
          window.location = 'blog.php';
          e.preventDefault();
        }else{
          if (formulario.articulo.value.length > 500) {
            alert ("Limite permitido en el articulo hasta 500 caracteres o llena todos los campos :(");
            window.location = 'blog.php';
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        }
      };
        var validar = function(e){
        validarTextArea(e);
    };
      formulario.addEventListener("submit",validar);

  }())
</script>

<div class="container">
<table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Fecha</th>
                        <th>Titulo</th>
                        <th>Autor</th>
                        <th>Contenido</th>
                        <th>Acciones</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM articulo";
                        $resul = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resul)) { ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $row['fecha']?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['titulo_articulo']?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['autor_articulo']?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['contenido']?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['id_articulo']?>" class="btn btn-outline-success"><i class="far fa-edit"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id_articulo']?>" class="btn btn-outline-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
</div>
</div>

<?php include ("includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

Y este es mi *header* donde tengo la sesión:

```
<?php
  error_reporting(0); 
  session_start();
  if (empty($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
      header("Location:../index.php");
  }
  ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>AGROCONTABLE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a3a8d3af24.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" id="navbar">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="../img/logoIcono.ico" width="70" height="70" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
    </a>
  <strong class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="textos">AGROCONTABLE</strong><br>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item" id="cambio">
        <a class="nav-link">Gestiona tu Produccion Agropecuaria</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" acttion="nabvarBlog.php" method="POST">
    <a class="mr-sm-2"><i class="far fa-user"></i><?php echo "Bienvenido $_SESSION[usuario]";?></a>
    <button class="form-control mr-sm-2 btn btn-outline-danger" type="submit" name="btnSalir"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Salir</button>
  </form>
  </div>
</nav>
<?php
error_reporting(0); 
  $salir = $_POST['btnSalir'];
  if (isset($salir)) {
      session_destroy();
      header("Location:../index.php");
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Parece ser que no estas utilizando `session_start()` en el archivo de validacion del login, por lo tanto `$_SESSION['usuario']` esta vacio en el resto de archivos.

Answer (score 3):

El problema pareces tenerlo en las siguientes líneas:

```
<?php
  error_reporting(0); 
  $salir = $_POST['btnSalir'];
  if (isset($salir)) {
    session_destroy();
    header("Location:../index.php");
  }
?>
```

La condición `if (isset($salir))` siempre se te va a cumplir dado que en la línea anterior `$salir = $_POST['btnSalir'];`, le llegue o no le llegue un valor a la variable `$salir`desde `$_POST`, va a estar definida y su valor va a ser algo distinto a `NULL`.

> isset — Determina si una variable está definida y no es NULL

Una posible solución sería comprobar si contiene algún valor además de existir. Podríamos hacerlo mediante la función `empty()` de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
  error_reporting(0); 
  $salir = $_POST['btnSalir'];
  if (isset($salir)) {
    if (!empty($salir)) {
      session_destroy();
      header("Location:../index.php");
    }
  }
?>
```

De esta manera, controlarás que solamente se te destruya la sesión y se te haga la redirección cuando el usuario pulse `btnSalir`.

Otra opción sería hacer el uso de la función `isset()` sobre `$_POST`, sin llegar a asignarlo a ninguna variable:

```
<?php
  error_reporting(0); 
  if (isset($_POST['btnSalir'])) {
    session_destroy();
    header("Location:../index.php");
  }
?>
```

**Referencias:** [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php), [empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a los que respondieron, de echo me sirvió, pero el problema radicaba en mi pagina principal, por masa que tuviera bien las sesiones solo iba a funcionar una vez y ya por que tenia este código para los mensajes de alerta, lo que no sabia era que me estaba afectando todas las sesiones.

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['message'])){?>
    <div class="alert alert-<?= $_SESSION['message_typed'] ?> alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <?= $_SESSION['message'] ?>
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    </div>
<?php session_unset(); }?>
```

Mas precisamente el "`session_unset();`" que como lo dice en la documentación libera todas las variables de sesión.